# Add space between input and button in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and have this HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <label class="control-label" for="parameterValue">sdsd</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="parameterValue" placeholder="Enter a value..." />
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default btn-success">Update</button></span>
                </div>
                <label class="control-label" for="parameterValue">sdsd</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="parameterValue" placeholder="Enter a value..." />
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default btn-success">Update</button></span>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.completeStep">Complete Step</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samholder/jx57u8hs/1/)

I want the final button to be spaced away vertically from the `input-group` div and not touching it.

An example I found using a form has the button spaced out: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samholder/juoz59dr/)

and this is how I'd like my button. How can I get that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply wrap each pair of `<label>` and `<div class="input-group">` by a `<div>` having `.form-group` class. *(Or just wrap the last pair if needed so)*

The reason is that twitter bootstrap applies a `margin-bottom` of `15px` to `.form-group`. You could also do this manually by giving the `<button>` a top margin or giving the last input a bottom margin.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/jx57u8hs/2/)**

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="parameterValue">sdsd</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="parameterValue" placeholder="Enter a value..." />
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default btn-success">Update</button></span>
                </div>                    
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="parameterValue">sdsd</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="parameterValue" placeholder="Enter a value..." />
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default btn-success">Update</button></span>
                </div>                    
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.completeStep">Complete Step</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept when I get up in the morning, as need to wait at the moment.